# How does .@2x work

Tags: iphone, background, background-image

I am new at formatting my code to fit the iphone (especially 4 and 5). Do you add two images to the css (with no media query)? Or do you need a media query with that background image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically yes, you need to do the following:

```
    .repeatingPattern {
     background: url(../images/bgPattern.png) repeat;
     background-size: 100px 100px;
}

@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
     .repeatingPattern {
          background: url(../images/bgPattern@2x.png) repeat;
     }
}
```

but if you are using jquery it will be more efficient to do that like this:

```
<img class="hires" alt="" src="search.png" width="100" height="100" />
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {

    if (window.devicePixelRatio == 2) {

          var images = $("img.hires");

          // loop through the images and make them hi-res
          for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {

            // create new image name
            var imageType = images[i].src.substr(-4);
            var imageName = images[i].src.substr(0, images[i].src.length - 4);
            imageName += "@2x" + imageType;

            //rename image
            images[i].src = imageName;
          }
     }

});
</script>
```

Comment: I am having a lot of problems with the background image not rendering correctly. If you are efficient in Iphone IOS, mobile safari - could we chat some?